# Transform Polynomial in Trigonometric Functions to AssociatedLegendrePolynomials

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, groebner-bases

I want to transform a polynomial in `Sin` and `Cos` to AssociatedLegendrePolynomials.

I have a working code, but the end result is not the most simple one (for example it gives a sum of 3 ALP that can be expressed as a single one).

Furthermore, I have to specify the maximum order that `Sin` and `Cos` appear in beforehand, so it doesn't scale too nicely.

```
transformALP[cosN_?IntegerQ, sinN_?IntegerQ] :=
 Module[{
   max = sinN + cosN + 1,
   sum,
   cl,
   wanted,
   reversed,
   variables,
   solved,
   rules = {}
   },
  sum = Sum[
    c[l, m] SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], 0], {l, 0, max}, {m, 0,
      l}];  
  cl = CoefficientList[
    sum, {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {max + 1, max + 1}];
  wanted = cl[[cosN + 1, sinN + 1]];
  variables = Variables[wanted];
  If[Length@variables == 0, Print["==0: ", sum, " ", wanted]; 
   Return[]];
  If[Length@variables > 1, 
   Print["Error: Variable length should be 1.: ", variables]; 
   Return[]];
  AppendTo[rules, 
   variables[[1]] -> 1/Coefficient[wanted, variables[[1]]]];
  reversed = Flatten@Reverse@cl;
  For[i = 1, i <= Length@reversed, ++i,
   reversed = reversed /. rules;
   solved = Solve[reversed[[i]] == 0, Variables[reversed[[i]]]];
   AppendTo[rules, #] & /@ Flatten[solved];
   ];
  (Sum[c[l, m] Sqrt[(2 l + 1)/(4 \[Pi])] Sqrt[(l - m)!/(l + m)!]
        apl[l, m], {l, 0, max}, {m, 0, l}] /. rules) // Simplify
  ]
Clear[apl];
alpRules = 
  Drop[Rule[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
    Reverse@Flatten[
      Table[{ Cos[\[Theta]]^a Sin[\[Theta]]^b, 
        transformALP[a, b]}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}], {1, 2}], -1];
```

Usage

```
Cos[\[Theta]]Sin[\[Theta]]^2 /.alpRules
1/15 alp[3,2]
```

Comment: The associated Legendre polynomials are over-complete. How do you define "simplest"? BTW the maximal power can be determined by e.g. `trigExponent[expr_,arg_]:=Module[{t},Exponent[expr//TrigExpand//ReplaceAll[{Sin[arg]->t,Cos[arg]->t}],t]]`, and `trigExponent[Cos[2 x] Sin[x]^2,x]` gives `4`

Answer (score 1):

The functions:

```
LegendreP[n,x] Sqrt([2n+1)/2]
```

are an orthogonal system of functions over -1.. 1 with the weight function: 1.

Therefore, you can get the expansion coefficients of e.g.:

```
f[x_]=Cos[x]Sin[x]^2
```

simply by:

```
nmax = 10;
f[x_] = Cos[x] Sin[x]^2;
coefs = Table[
    NIntegrate[
     f[x] LegendreP[n, x] Sqrt[(2 n + 1)/2], {x, -1, 1}] , {n, 0, 
     nmax}] // Quiet;
f1[x_] = 
  coefs . Table[LegendreP[n, x] Sqrt[(2 n + 1)/2], {n, 0, nmax}];
Plot[{f[x] , f1[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

The difference between the oiginal function an the expansion with nmax=10:

```
Plot[{f[x] - f1[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your efforts but I fail to see how this addresses my question.  I need an output like `alp[3,2]` for the input. When I execute your code and look a the coefficients, I get a gibberish mix of trigonmetric functions at integer coordinates and polynomials in `x`.

Comment: You write "I want to transform a polynomial in Sin and Cos to LegendrePolynomials" In general, this gives an expansion with a infinite numbers of terms. Therefore you need to truncate the expansion somewhere, depending on the required accuracy. You can get a numeric output of the coefficients, instead of the "gibberish" by wrapping them with `N`

Comment: Okay, I agree with that point. Maybe you missed it in the example, but I'm actually talking about the associated legendre polynomials (edited the title accordingly) and there is a very clear way to do it (as seen in the example).